# JSX element type 'Route' does not have any construct or call signatures - route problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have got error with Route "message": "JSX element type 'Route' does not have any construct or call signatures."

in Browser:
./src/app/layout/App.tsx
Attempted import error: 'react-router-dom' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Route').

Really I don`t know what is wrong.

```
import React from "react";
import NavBar from "../../features/nav/NavBar";
import Footer from "../../features/footer/Footer";
import Route, { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "../../features/dashboard/Dashboard";
import TestApiDashboard from "../../features/testApiDashboard/TestApiDashboard";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="main">
        <NavBar />
        <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/testApiDashboard" component={TestApiDashboard} />
        <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

[image]

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import './app/layout/styles.css';
import App from './app/layout/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import differently as the following:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Instead of your code snippet:

```
import Route, { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

You can read further at [`<Route />`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route). I hope this helps!

Comment: Very welcome @RafałDeveloper! I suggest to read through the added `<Route />` link also. Happy to help!